# how to compose a video with mask on another video

Tags: android, video, mask

I'm new to android. What I need is to play 2 videos at the same time exactly on top of each other. By applying a bitmap mask on the top video the bottom video will be revealed through the mask. I only found the answer of how to overlay an image with a bitmap mask. Any help would be appreciated. Please give a complete code if possible. Thank you